# For which values of t does a matrix not have eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, parametric

I need help solving this problem
"For which values of real parameter t does the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
π^2t^2 & 36\\
-36 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

NOT have real eigenvalues.
Thank you.

Comment: Real eigenvalues? Because a matrix always has eigenvalues if complex values are considered.

Comment: Yes, real eigenvalues, I forgot to specify that.

Comment: Write out the characteristic equation, which is a quadratic polynomial. Then look at the discriminant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we compute the characteristic equation we find that the eigenvalues are the solutions to
$$\begin{align}
-\lambda(\pi^2t^2-\lambda)+36^2 &= \lambda^2-\lambda \pi^2t^2 +36^2\\
&= 0
\end{align}$$
Using the quadratic formula we find that
$$\lambda=\frac{\pi^2t^2\pm\sqrt{\pi^4t^4-4\cdot 36^2}}{2}$$
The eigenvalues are real if and only if
$$\pi^4t^4-4\cdot 36^2>0$$
$$t^4>\frac{4\cdot36^2}{\pi^4}$$
Square rooting both sides
$$t^2<-\frac{2\cdot 36}{\pi^2}\quad\text{or}\quad t^2>\frac{2\cdot 36}{\pi^2}$$
Again square rooting
$$|t|<i6\pi\sqrt{2}\quad\text{or}\quad |t|>6\pi\sqrt{2}$$
If you are dealing with real $t$ this means that $t\in(-\infty,-6\pi\sqrt{2})\cup (6\pi\sqrt{2},\infty)$.

Comment: That's it, it wasn't that hard actually, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: calculate the determinant of 
\begin{bmatrix}
π^2t^2 - \lambda & 36\\
-36 & -\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}, the result will be a second order polynomial in $\lambda$, set it to zero, and try ABC formula (specificly, check when the determinant > 0).